Does Luke's gospel leave open that Satan repented and became an apostle, so as to make his concept of χάρις=grace pivotal?
This question is about whether Luke writes the devil as a literary antagonist - having it present a snide anti-lesson that God nullifies by the resurrection - so as to make his gospel's resolution depend on χάρις, as a distinctively Lukan concept?

Luke 23:38 - - Ο ΒΑΣΙΛΕΥΣ ΤΩΝ ΙΟΥΔΑΙΩΝ ΟΥΤΟΣ
This is a mocking way of stating the charge:
(e.g. https://www.ligonier.org/learn/devotionals/king-of-jews-crucified)
But what if it's also Satan paying lip-service to Jesus' kingship? Publicly announcing him, in writing, as the King of the Jews in their prophecies e.g. Isaiah 6:5. (Which the relational genitive can also do or we wouldn't sense any irony.)
Since a gospel is generically concerned with announcing the coming of God's kingdom, and establishing that Jesus ticks all the prophetic boxes, is the Titulus even more contemptuous as a TLDR? Or an INB4?
Luke shows one of the requirements for salvation is to acknowledge Jesus as king:-

Luke 23:41: And we indeed justly, for we are receiving the due reward of our deeds; but this man has done nothing wrong.”
Luke 23:42: And he said, “Jesus, remember me when you come into your kingdom.”
Luke 23:43: And he said to him, “Truly, I say to you, today you will be with me in paradise.”

The only other thing the penitent thief does is to repent. He's the last worker to the vineyard in the parable, arriving right at the end of the shift. Or is he?
Luke 23:47: Now when the centurion saw what had taken place, he praised God, saying, “Certainly this man was innocent!”

The Centurion might be the faithful centurion from Luke 7; or a member of whichever Roman legion was in charge of the executions that day (Tenth Legion Fretensis?) ; or a possessed spokesperson from that other Legion, in the Gadarene swine story. A legion being represented by one of the centurions might leave diplomatic wriggle-room for the legatus[?] - like an equivocal repentance.

If Luke was working to the ancient-and-still-going literary convention for how to write strong antagonists - did this also contribute to his theology by closing off salvation without grace?

UPDATE (29/08/2024)
I wouldn't have thought Luke as a literary undertaking is controversial, given his gospel opens with a literary preface, but there is good scholarly discussion of it here:-
https://archive.org/details/synopticproblemw00good/page/160/mode/2up?q=literary
Luke and John use Grace as theological keyword, but not Mark or Matthew:-
https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_5485.htm
If he makes it pivotal to his plot structure, that might be evidence that his concept is more similar than it looks to Paul's, given his usages are narrative not definitive.

I am not sure how to even approach this question - perhaps I am overly stupid, but I cannot work out what this question is even about.

ok I've removed the humour for you - does Luke write the devil this way towards introducing χάρις as a specifically Lukan concept?

I can't understand the point of the question either. Luke faithfully wrote of Jesus of Nazareth conveying staggering truth which has 'turned the world upside down'. I think the OP should read Luke's epistle again and simply drink in what Luke reports.

@Dottard please be kind in your voting, I can't be expected to know very much about anything yet when I've only asked 14 questions and some of them are still unanswered

@NigelJ wouldn't exegesis then be posis? A drinking? If that's all it is, why the downvotes? There are four and a half nearly-consecutive lines of the holy scripture here in this question - we can let them fill us

@FelixLXX Voting is both voluntary and private therefore I cannot comment.

@NigelJ thanks for that remark +1

@FelixLXX You are most welcome.

Felix - I have not voted here at all - those downvotes are from others.

Demons can say truth and often do, so what? Also hypocrite men, who are viler than demons, say good things, so what? If a cannibal gives an eloquent lecture about ills of eating human flesh, will it avail for anything?
Similarly, demons believe in God and tremble (James 2:19); they tremble because God for them is not the source of joy and bliss, but of torment. If I am a hater of Leo Messi, I can reluctantly admit and confess that he is one of the GOATs of football on the level of Pelé and Maradona, but my sincere confession will be done with a grudging and hateful heart. Similar is demons' true confession of Christ, it is not at all repentance-driven or repentance-generating confession.

Jesus doesn't take the penitent thief for a hypocrite, but presumably must take Luke's Satan as one. Is that the operation of Grace - χάρις being a concept Luke might be first to introduce - or is there written a difference between the demon and the saved sinner?

For one thing, the devil and his angels are not humans. Humans were deceived in the Garden of Eden, so God found a way to rescue humans, but created the Lake of Fire for the devil and his angels--and those who choose to reject the Messiah, the only Son of God who was tortured to death to deliver us and give us the hope of resurrection! This is the wonderful message of the Gospels as was prophesied. From the humanity that the devil through the serpent wanted to murder, came the Seed of Eve to destroy the serpent and the devil, who will suffer for eternity for all the suffering he caused us.

@Dieter I fully agree but with the phrase: “for all the suffering he caused us”; poor demons are not punished for their misdeeds agains us in a judiciary way, they are punished even without any reference to human race, by their sheer rejection of God, for this is the acme and root of all torments. Had God, hypothetically, not created humans, still demons would be miserably tormented by their own disobedience, for God loves and pities them, yet repentance is blocked to them due to their recalcitrance and arrogance.

The general format of a well written question is to ask a single clear question in the title.
In the body of the post the Bible passage in question should be quoted with enough context to demonstrate the verse or passage is not being mis-quoted followed by any clarification of the question that might be needed. The goal of the post should be to provide a single question clearly asked.

In trying to decipher this question here is what was written:
Question title -

Does Luke's gospel leave open that Satan repented and became an apostle, so as to make his concept of χάρις=grace pivotal?

Question body -

This question is about whether Luke writes the devil as a literary antagonist - having it present a snide anti-lesson that God nullifies by the resurrection - so as to make his gospel's resolution depend on χάρις, as a distinctively Lukan concept?

The title indicates a question about Satan's repentance in Luke's gospel.
Breaking apart the first paragraph we get other questions and no clarification.

Luke using the devil as a literary antagonist
having it ("it" what?) present a snide anti-lesson that God nullifies by the resurrection
The "snide anti-lesson allows Luke to make his gospel's resolution depend on χάρις as a distinctly Lukan concept.

Next part of the question

Luke 23:38 - - Ο ΒΑΣΙΛΕΥΣ ΤΩΝ ΙΟΥΔΑΙΩΝ ΟΥΤΟΣ

My guess is that the "it" in point number 2 is the sign placed over Jesus head on the cross.
Luke 23:38

There was a written notice above him, which read: this is the king of the jews.


The post goes on.
I'll stop here to answer the questions that have been asked so far.

Does Luke's gospel leave open that Satan repented and became an apostle, so as to make his concept of χάρις=grace pivotal?

No. There is nothing in Luke 23:38 that indicates Satan repented and became an apostle. Further, I'd offer that there is nowhere in all the Bible that indicates the repentance of Satan.

Is Luke using Satan as a literary antagonist?

No. There is nothing in Luke 23:38 that supports Luke using Satan as a literary antagonist.
Is the sign placed over Jesus head

a snide anti-lesson that God nullifies by the resurrection

No. The passage does not support the sigh placed over Jesus head as being a snide anti-lesson.
In John 19 we have more information about the sign.

19 Pilate had a notice prepared and fastened to the cross. It read: jesus of nazareth, the king of the jews. 20 Many of the Jews read this sign, for the place where Jesus was crucified was near the city, and the sign was written in Aramaic, Latin and Greek. 21 The chief priests of the Jews protested to Pilate, “Do not write ‘The King of the Jews,’ but that this man claimed to be king of the Jews.”
22 Pilate answered, “What I have written, I have written.”

The author of this question has what seems to be the clearest statement of the question in the comments to the question.

does Luke write the devil this way towards introducing χάρις as a specifically Lukan concept?

The passage referenced - Luke 23:38 does not reference the devil. Grace is not a specifically Lukan concept. "Grace" appears 114 times in the ESV translation of the New Testament:
Luke (1)
John (3)
Acts (11)
Romans (18)
1 Corinthians (5)
2 Corinthians (11)
Galatians (8)
Ephesians (11)
Philippians (3)
Colossians (4)
1 Thessalonians (2)
2 Thessalonians (4)
1 Timothy (4)
2 Timothy (4)
Titus (4)
Philemon (2)
Hebrews (6)
James (1)
1 Peter (6)
2 Peter (2)
2 John (1)
Jude (1)
Revelation (2)

are any of those thought to be before Luke?
